# Notifications with BLE Android and iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to create a BLE device that connects to the phone and receive all notifications (Text message, incoming calls, emails)

It should be cross plateform and stay connected all the time.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 7):

Android and iOS are very very different regarding this question.

**iOS 7-8**

On iOS, your app have no way to know when you receive SMS, emails etc... So there's nothing you can do on the phone side to receive notifications and then send it to the phone via BLE.

(Also, you do know that iphone is very restrictive on apps running in the background)

The one and only way to go is Apple Notification Center Service : [Official Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html)
[Human readable explanation](http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/63658238857/the-apple-notification-center-service-or-wtf-is)

Here's how it works. Make your external hardware go into central mode (e.g. "master mode", not the usual ppheral mode), then ask the ios device to turn on the ANCS service using a "Service Sollicitation"
Pairing might be needed to do so.

You device can then connect to this service (Warning, [ANCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW7) is not the standard SIG [ANS](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.alert_notification.xml) 1811 service !)

No app is required, all is done on the hardware side.

**Android 4.3-4.4**

Prior to android 5.0, android devices could only be in Central mode, and never in Peripheral mode, so there's no way to emulate the iOS behavior.

The only way to send notifications to your BLE hardware is to have your external hardware in Peripheral mode, then create a proprietary protocol for sending notifications using your phone in Central mode. (yep, the inverse as Apple)

It is very easy and very straightforward to listen to notifications by extending a NotificationListenerService. [Example implementation](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html) Just don't forget to fire intent android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS to open Notification Access setting screen and grant access to this app.

Now the issue is : it is very difficult to maintain a BLE connection due to the different instabilities of the android BLE stack and you have very little control over your service's lifespan when on background, so keeping it alive isn't an option either. (ah, and don't try to bind a Service inside the NotificationListenerService, it won't work)

So the only thing to do, is to program a short BLE class, (that works outside of a Service) that will quickly start a connection, send the message send shut down.

Lots of android phones are unstable on the Pairing function. So ideally, the external hardware should use a "Just work" connection on android (when he's a peripheral) and a Pairing connection when he's a Central (on ios)

As usual with BLE in android, you will want to queue all requests etc...